# Importing Library in Python does not work

Tags: python, pip

Using both Visual Studio 1.86.0 and Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 the error is the same:

```
Import "lxml" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
```

Trying this basic example from Android tutorial:

```
from lxml import html

html_content = """
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
           Test
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
"""

# Analisar o conteúdo HTML
tree = html.fromstring(html_content)


xpath_expression = "//div/p"

result = tree.xpath(xpath_expression)

for element in result:
    print(html.tostring(element, pretty_print=True))
```

Lxml Installation:

```
pip install lxml
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in c:\users\base 6\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-pac
kages\python311\site-packages (5.1.0)
```

In terminal it prints for pip (as it is in tutotial):

```
pip show lxml
Name: lxml
Version: 5.1.0
Summary: Powerful and Pythonic XML processing library combining libxml2/libxslt with the ElementTree API.
Home-page: https://lxml.de/
Author-email: lxml-dev@lxml.de
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: C:\Users\Base 6\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\
LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
PS C:\Users\Base 6\source\repos\Python> pip --version
pip 23.3.1 from C:\Users\Base 6\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\
LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)
```

Printing sys.path:

```
import sys; print(sys.path)
```

Output:

```
'C:\\Users\\Base 6\\source\\repos\\PythonTest\\PythonTest',
'C:\\Users\\Base 6\\source\\repos\\PythonTest\\PythonTest', 
'C:\\Users\\Base 6\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.zip', 
'C:\\Users\\Base 6\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Users\\Base 6\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib',
'C:\\Users\\Base 6\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312',
'C:\\Users\\Base 6\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages'] –
```

Comment: I think you have two different installations of python on your computer.  Please edit the question and add the output of this code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Yes, you have two separate installations of python on your computer.  Pip is using the one in `C:\Users\Base 6\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0`, but vs code is using the one in `C:\Users\Base 6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312`.

Comment: @JohnGordon Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: **Please read** the linked duplicate in order to understand the problem. Having multiple installations of Python on your computer is **not wrong, and often useful**. However, you must make sure to install libraries like `lxml` *for the Python that will be used to run the code*.